# what is the terminal command in windows for creating a react ionic app with Cordova ? I tried searching but didn't get anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, cordova, npm

what is the terminal command in windows for creating a react ionic app with Cordova ?

I am trying to shift my react app into an react-ionic app , and I don't want to use capacitor instead I want to use the Cordova , but I'm not getting the terminal command for this , please help me get this solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command -

```
ionic start myReactApp blank --type=react --cordova
```

Adding `--cordova` will include Cordova integration

Comment: thanks a lot buddy , this worked for me !!